# Как работать с InputStream.read()? Как выйти из блокировки или избежать её?

Tags: java, input

В общем вопрос достаточно непростой, но уже не в первый раз с этим сталкиваюсь.

Пусть есть устройство, с которым мы обмениваемся данными. Послали что-то и ждем ответа, без которого мы не можем продолжить работать. И в случае проблемы с соединением всё хорошо - выбросится исключение от read и мы выйдем из функции. Но а что если будет какая то логическая ошибка в этом устройстве и оно просто не выдаст ответ? Получается мы будет ждать его вечно и программа просто напросто зависнет, а это некрасиво по отношению к пользователю. Значит нужен какой то таймаут.

Так вот, как его обеспечить я не знаю. Когда то для лабы в универе я по советам препода запускал считывание в отдельном потоке, а по таймауту поток убивал через itterapt или что-то в таком духе. Только вот на самом-то деле поток под windows скорее всего не будет завершен (та и не только там, в андроиде тоже так не удавалось убить поток). А это значит что останется поток, запущенный, никому не нужный, но готовый считать первый же пришедший символ. Что как я понимаю может привести к тому, что следующий ответ от устройства нам придет криво.

Была идея использовать available для проверки, могу ли я что-то считать, и если ничего не появилось в течении некоторого времени - даже не запускать чтение.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Таймаут можно установить на "первоисточнике" стрима. Например для сокета есть возможность установить таймаут. Тогда и стримы на основе сокета будут с таймаутом. read будет кидаться исключениями. Если нет таймаута на "первоисточнике", тогда можно перейти на NIO. У селектора NIO есть вариант с таймаутом. Но NIO сильно сложнее стримов.

Answer (score -1):

Установить таймаут на чтение из сокета можно методом `socket.setSoTimout(int)`, где `int` — время в миллисекундах.